# Set nested property of json object using brackets notation in PUT request (svelte + strapi)

Tags: javascript, request, put, svelte, strapi

I'm using Svelte and Strapi for the project.
Here is a simplified version of my problem:

The json where I want to send my PUT request. (`localhost:1337/shapes/1`)

```json
{
  id: 1,
  name: 'square',
  colors: {
    red: false,
    blue: false,
    green: false
  }
}
```

The toggle buttons in svelte template:

```html
{#each shapes as shape}
  <div on:click={toggleColor(shape, "red")}>red</div>
  <div on:click={toggleColor(shape, "blue")}>blue</div>
  <div on:click={toggleColor(shape, "green")}>green</div>
{/each}
```

The toggle function (see comments to find what's missing):

```js
function toggleColor(shape, color) {
  let index = shapes.indexOf(shape);

  axios.put(`http://localhost:1337/shapes/${shape.id}`, {
    // How to write this part to toggle a color?
    // The commented code below doesn't work as it doesn't set a color without  
    // reseting others siblings
    // colors: {
    //   [color]: shape.colors[color] ? false : true
    // }
  })
  .then((res) => {
    coins[index].colors[color] = res.data.colors[color];
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log(err.message)
  });
}
```

To understand more clearly what happens with this version, it returns this response if I click on `blue button` then `red button`:

```json
{
  id: 1,
  name: 'square',
  colors: {
    red: true,
    blue: null,
    green: null
  }
}
```

Expected response:

```json
{
  id: 1,
  name: 'square',
  colors: {
    red: true,
    blue: true,
    green: false
  }
}
```

Comment: What is the response you're expecting when you click the blue button then the red button?

Comment: I modified my post to add expected response

Comment: And what does this route `http://localhost:1337/shapes/${shape.id}` do when you make a request to it? can you show us the code?

Comment: @AdilBimzagh if `shape.id` equals `1` then just look at the json at the top of my post to see response.

Comment: Well, that's the problem, your route only resets all colors to `false`, instead, you must save the last click values somewhere and then check it every time you hit that route.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You was almost there. The following code:

```js
{
  colors: {
    [color]: shape.colors[color] ? false : true
  }
}
```

...will redefine `colors` as an object with only a single color in it. To also get the previous colors, use the [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) like:

```js
{
  colors: {
    ...shape.colors,
    [color]: shape.colors[color] ? false : true
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you see the response he gets when he hits this route `http://localhost:1337/shapes/${shape.id}` ? it resets all colors to false.

Comment: Thanks Johann, this is the notation I was looking for! It works as desired.

Comment: @n355 No problem please don't forget to upvote and validate the answer please :)

Comment: @johannchopin Yesterday, I wasn't able to upvote due to missing reputation score. (I'm not an active user). Now it's ok. Thanks again ;)